# In a ComboBox, how can I format the names in the dropdown using XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am using WPF + MVVM.

If I have a ComboBox, normally the names listed in the `Dropdown` are is defined by the `.ToString()` overload on the contents of the `ObservableCollection`.

Is there a way to control the names in the `Dropdown` list using XAML instead of the `.ToString()` overload?

*What I have tried*

I've spent a lot of time on this. The only solution I have come up with so far is to inherit from the original class, and define a new `.ToString()` override, but this solution is ugly, ugly, ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the ItemTemplate.

E.g.

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Name}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Or what you can do if you only want to display a specific field, is to use `DisplayMemberPath`

e.g.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PhonebookEntries}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          SelectedValuePath="Name" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=PhonebookEntry}" />
```

Comment: Tried this, it worked absolutely perfectly. Deleted all of the old, ugly C#, now everything is clean and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding to an `ObservableCollection<T>.` If you don't tell the binding engine what property to bind to in `T`, it will call `.ToString()` on the `T` class and place the results in a TextBlock.

Let's say you have a class, `Trip`

```
public class Trip
{
    public string TripName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

To show the `TripName` in ComboBox, use a `DataTemplate` (as suggested by Michal).  This allows you to specify what type of elements are used to render the bound data and what properties to bind to.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Trips}">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TripName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```

To bind to a different property use another property name:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description }" />
```

Comment: This solution is an order of magnitude more elegant than mine, thanks!!